# Extracting some texts from txt file and adding to an existing file bash

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, command-line

all experts

I have two types of files in the same directory

ex1) record1.txt   (record2, record3, record4 ...)

```
11111 absda qwedc
11112 uiyds dqeds
11113 eqwev jfsec ...
```

ex2) Summary1.txt (Summary2, Summary3, Summary4 ...)

```
----some data is written---- 
.....
.....
***RESULT 111.114 30.344 90.3454***  OTHERNUMBER#1 OTHERNUMBER#2 ..... 
.....
.....
```

All I want to do is extract ***RESULT X(number) Y(number) Z(number)*** of Summary#.txt. 
And then, put those positions into the corresponding record#.txt, but I want to add some information, like this

```
X Y Z
111.114 30.344 90.3459

11111 absda qwedc
11112 uiyds dqeds
11113 eqwev jfsec ...
```

So, I want my final file, record#.txt, to look above.
I tried sed and cat... 
all failed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undersand you correctly, this is my proposal:

```
for i in record*.txt; do
  xyz=$(grep -oP "(?<=RESULT ).*(?=\*\*\*)" $i)
  sed -i "1 iX Y Z\n$xyz\n" summary${i//record/}
done
```

---

Loop through the files named `record*.txt`

```
for i in record*.txt; do
```

---

Capture the string between `RESULT` and `***`

```
xyz=$(grep -oP "(?<=RESULT ).*(?=\*\*\*)" $i)
```

---

Add X Y Z in the first line, following by the captured pattern, in the file `summary*.txt`

```
sed -i "1 iX Y Z\n$xyz\n" summary${i//record/}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple concatenation of a line with fixed text (`X Y Z`) and part of a single line from one file (`SummaryX.txt`) and the entire contents of another file with a related filename (`recordX.txt`)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for sfile in Summary*.txt; do
  rfile="$(echo "$sfile" | sed -e 's/^Summary/record/')"
  ofile="$rfile.new"

  {
    echo X Y Z

    sed -E -n -e 's/^.*RESULT ([0-9.]+ [0-9.]+ [0-9.]+).*/\1/p' "$sfile"
    echo

    cat "$rfile"
  } > "$ofile"

  # uncomment the following to replace the original record file with the new one.
  # mv -f "$ofile" "$rfile"
done
```

You haven't said which shell you're using, so this doesn't use any bash-specific string manipulations or other features.  It should work with any sh-compatible shell.

The output will be stored in `recordX.txt.new` unless you uncomment the `mv` line.  This is so that you can verify that it does what you want **before** it destroys your original input files (you should be working on backup copies anyway when doing something potentially destructive).

```
$ cat record1.txt.new 
X Y Z
111.114 30.344 90.3454

11111 absda qwedc
11112 uiyds dqeds
11113 eqwev jfsec ...
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!

Comment: no problem.  btw, upvoting and/or accepting an answer (by clicking on the tick mark to the left) is [how we say thanks on stack exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)